# Multiplicity of a root of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $F \subseteq E$ be a field extension. Let $\alpha \in E$ be a root of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ over $F$ of multiplicity $3$. Let $\beta$ be any other root of $f(x)$ in $E$. What is the multiplicity of $\beta$?

I considered the following example: 
$$f(x)=(x^2+1)^3(x^2+4)$$

Here the multiplicity of $i$ is three and multiplicity of $2i$ is one. Similarly I can consider other examples and multiplicity of $\beta$ could be $2$ or $3$ (or more).

However, the answer given is $3$. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit:** I realized my mistake here. An irreducible polynomial in a field of characteristic $0$ has no multiple roots. Thus characteristic of $F$ is prime, say $p$. As $f$ has multiple roots, therefore $f(x)=g(x^p)$.

How do I go on from here?

Comment: Oops, I misread it!

Comment: $f(x)=(x^2+1)^3(x^2+4)$ is clearly not irreducible (in fact, it has at least $4$ prime factors in $F[x]$ for any field $F\supseteq \Bbb Q$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All roots of an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$ have the same multiplicity.

Assume $a$ is a root of polynomial $f(x) \in F[x]$ of multplicity $\ge k$. Then $a$ is also a root of the $f^{(k-1)}$.

Now assume $f(b)=0$ but $f^{(k-1)}(b)\ne0$. Then $f^{(k-1)}$ is not the zero polynomial and  $\gcd(f,f^{(k-1)})$ is a nontrivial divisor of $f$.

Comment: I think proof makes implicit assumptions on the characteristic of the underlying field, because higher derivatives do not detect multiplicity in the non-separable case. It can be mended by using Hasse derivatives or Cauchy modules.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen a proof in this site that does not use characteristic $0$ of the base field as hypothesis. I will prove it for an arbitrary field $K$. Let $p \in K[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial and let $\alpha, \beta \in F$ be roots of $p$, where $F$ is the splitting field of $p$. Thus, there exits a isomorphism of fields

$$\varphi : K(\alpha) \to K(\beta)$$

such that $\phi|_K = Id_{K}$ and $\varphi(\alpha) = \beta$. Because $F$ is the splitting field of $p$, $F$ is a finite extension of $K$, and because $F$ is the splitting field of a polynomial in $K[X]$, the extension $F/K$ is normal. Therefore, the isomorphism $\varphi$ may be extended to an automorphism
$$ \psi: F \to F$$
Now, consider the canonical factorization of $p$ in $F[X]$:
$$p(X) = a \prod_{j=1}^n (x-a_j)^{c_j},$$
we may say that $a_1 = \alpha$, $a_2 =\beta$. Applying the natural extension of $\psi$
$$ \overline{\psi} : F[X] \to F[X]$$
to $p$ we get:
$$a \prod_{j=1}^n (x-\psi(a_j))^{c_j}  $$
and, as $\psi$ fixes $K$ and $\psi$ is injective, $\psi(a_j)$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,n$ are all the roots of $p$. From here, the conclusion (that the multiplicity of $\alpha$ is the same as the one of $\beta$) should be easy to deduce.